# Creating a new environment with referencing

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, environments

I'm trying to create a referenceable "system" environment that basically displays an equation with a custom counter. Then I want to reference the environment with `autoref`, so as to have "System (S1)" as output when I reference it.

```
\newcounter{system}\setcounter{system}{0}

\newenvironment{system}{\refstepcounter{system}\begin{equation*}}{\hfill(S\arabic{system})
\end{equation*}}

\hyperref[system]{System~\ref{system}}
\def\systemautorefname{System}

\begin{system}
 \dot x=u(x),
\label{s1}
\end{system}
```

However, when I do

```
\autoref{s1}
```

I get an error saying that the reference `s1` is undefined. What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some remarks:

- The label has used the name `s1`, the references `system`. The label name must match, the example below uses `s1`.
- The use `equation*` indicates that probably package `amsmath` is used.
- With `amsmath` `\tag` can be used to print the equation number.
- Redefining `\p@system` helps to get the parentheses around the number, when it is referenced.
- I have put `\label` outside environment `equation` with the name as option to the environment `system` to avoid trouble with the redefinition of `\label` inside environments of `amsmath`.
- The star form of `\ref` avoids the link inside a link in the line with `\hyperref`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{system}
\renewcommand*{\thesystem}{S\arabic{system}}
\newcommand*{\systemautorefname}{System}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@system}{%
  \expandafter\p@@system
}
\newcommand*{\p@@system}[1]{%
  (#1)%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{system}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{system}%
  \ifx\\#1\\%
  \else
    \label{#1}%
  \fi
  \begin{equation}%
}{%
  \tag{\thesystem}%
  \end{equation}%
}

\begin{document}

\hyperref[s1]{System~\ref*{s1}}, \autoref{s1}

\begin{system}[s1]
 \dot x=u(x),
\end{system}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I probably never could have written that from scratch, but I've already learned a lot just from backwards engineering your code. Didn't even know there was a starred version of `\newcommand` until now.

Probably don't even need to mention that it works like a charm.