# Environment for chemical reaction with reference

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, mhchem

I need a chemical reaction environment, numbered and able to be referenced/labeled. It must also that is consistent with `equation` in its looks.
I have read many questions and my code is an adaptation of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82471/creating-a-new-environment-with-referencing).

However I would really like to be able to use the same default `\label`.

I don't need a *List of Reactions* as most other questions seems to seek.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath,}
\usepackage{mhchem}[version=4]
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\reactionlistname}{List of reactions}
\newlistof{reactions}{rxs}{\reactionlistname}


\newcounter{system}
\renewcommand*{\thesystem}{\arabic{system}}
\newcommand*{\systemautorefname}{Reaction}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\p@system}{%
    \expandafter\p@@system
}
\newcommand*{\p@@system}[1]{%
    #1%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{reaction}[1][]{%
    \refstepcounter{system}%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
    \label{#1}%
    \fi
    \begin{equation}%
}{%
    \tag{\thesystem}%
    \end{equation}%
}


\begin{document}

    You can see the chemical decomposition at \autoref{rea:bla} and its mathematical representation in \autoref{eq:foo}.


    \begin{equation}\label{eq:foo}
    t^2 + 27t
    \end{equation}


    \begin{reaction}[rea:bla]
        \ce{SiC + 2O2 -> CO2 + SiO2},
    \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Edit 1:

I've also tried `chemmacros`, [based on here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/number-mhchem-reactions-and-create-a-listofreactions),  but then I get `Equation 1` instead of `Reaction 1`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
    modules = {reactions} ,
    formula = mhchem
}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
You can see the chemical decomposition at \autoref{rea:bla} and its mathematical representation in \autoref{eq:foo}.


    \begin{equation}\label{eq:foo}
    t^2 + 27t
    \end{equation}


    \begin{reaction}\label{rea:bla}
        \ce{SiC + 2O2 -> CO2 + SiO2},
    \end{reaction}  
\end{document}
```

[image: Reaction and Equation]

Comment: Perhaps the packages loading order? Normally, `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (most notably `cleveref`).

Comment: @Bernard Good tip, I've checked in my main document, it's already like that. I will try again with the MWE.

Comment: How could `hyperref` know that it should write *Reaction*? There is no variable names!

Comment: @Sigur I have no idea. I thought the "module" reaction would do all the work for me... :(

Comment: Possibly related: [Customizing ref of reaction environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/456498/134144)

Comment: This works out of the box with `chemmacros` v6.1. Unrelated: using `\ce` inside a `reaction` is like doing `\ce{\ce{...}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code of a [previous answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467023/4427) and some additions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter % patchcmd from etoolbox, loaded by chemmacros
\patchcmd{\hyper@makecurrent}
 {\edef\Hy@param{#1}}
 {\xHy@param@def{#1}}
 {}{}
\def\xHy@param@def#1{%
  \edef\@tempa{\csname theH#1\endcsname}%
  \edef\@tempa{\expandafter\@car\@tempa\@nil}%
  \edef\Hy@param{\if R\@tempa reaction\else#1\fi}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\reactionautorefname{Reaction}

\chemsetup{
  modules = {reactions},
  formula = mhchem,
  reactions/tag-open=(R,
  reactions/tag-close=),
}

\begin{document}
You can see the chemical decomposition at \autoref{rea:bla} and its 
mathematical representation in \autoref{eq:foo}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:foo}
t^2 + 27t
\end{equation}
and there is a reaction
\begin{reaction}\label{rea:bla}
\ce{SiC + 2O2 -> CO2 + SiO2},
\end{reaction}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can define new `Reaction` command; I also would suggest to use `rxn` acronym instead of `rea` for better code readability (rxn stands exclusively for ["reaction"](https://www.acronymfinder.com/RXN.html), whereas "rea" has [numerous meanings](https://www.acronymfinder.com/REA.html)). Adapted from my [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456498/customizing-ref-of-reaction-environment/467020#467020):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        modules = {reactions},
        formula = mhchem,
        reactions/tag-open    = {(},
        reactions/tag-close   = {)},
    }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\rxnref}[1]{Reaction~\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
You can see the chemical decomposition at \rxnref{rxn:bla} and its mathematical representation in \autoref{eq:foo}.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:foo}
    t^2 + 27t
\end{equation}

\begin{reaction}\label{rxn:bla}
    \ce{SiC + 2O2 -> CO2 + SiO2}
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: All right, that is a very simple solution and I like it. However it will require me to use a different macro each time. I didn't fully understand why I can't use `\autoref` in this case, could you explain a bit more?

Comment: And also why its using curly braces instead of parenthesis, is it possible to change?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to make `\autoref` work nicely with reaction environment of `chemmacros`; `hyperref` doesn't offer anything chemistry-related out of the box that matter. As for changing the brackets, see the updated answer: this is done via passing arguments in `\chemsetup` (`reactions/tag-open` and `reactions/tag-close`).

Answer (score 1):

Since `chemmacros` v6.1 (2022/02/13) this works out of the box (the code below also removes the superfluous `\ce{}` in the `reaction` environment):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% \renewcommand\reactionautorefname{Reaction}

\chemsetup{
  formula = mhchem,
  reactions/tag-open=(R,
  reactions/tag-close=),
}

\begin{document}

You can see the chemical decomposition at \autoref{rea:bla} and its 
mathematical representation in \autoref{eq:foo}.
\begin{equation}\label{eq:foo}
  t^2 + 27t
\end{equation}
and there is a reaction
\begin{reaction}\label{rea:bla}
  SiC + 2O2 -> CO2 + SiO2,
\end{reaction}  

\end{document}
```

[image]